# A box BIGGER than... vs A BIGGER box than...?

Tags: difference

1. He gets a box **bigger** than the one I lost.
2. He gets a **bigger** box than the one I lost.

> **Is there any difference in the meaning of two of the above sentences** or those things are just about grammar, and they are the
>   same in meaning?

Ps. I got the 2nd sentence by applying the **postpositive-adjective** grammar stuff. You can enjoy that matter [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#General_uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences are both grammatically correct, and they mean essentially the same thing.  The only real difference is a slight difference in emphasis.

> He gets a bigger box than the one I lost.

This is the most common way that this would be phrased, so it's the most neutral in terms of emphasis:  He got a box, and it was bigger than the one you lost.

> He gets a box bigger than the one I lost.

This is a somewhat less common construction, so it actually emphasizes the word "bigger" a bit more:  He got a box, and not only that, but the box was actually bigger than the one you lost!

The difference in emphasis is not that large, so really either one could be substituted for the other without a problem..

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference in meaning since 1 compares objects and 2 compares boxes.  One can say "he gets a box bigger than the car I drive" but "he gets a bigger box than the car I drive" is comparing, well actually cars.  It sounds like "box" is some sort of model name or euphemism for a car then.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of this answer. In both sentences, **one** refers to a box. So in both sentences the **box gotten** is bigger than the **box lost**. Whether it's a **box bigger** or a **bigger box** makes no difference to the meaning.

Comment: @RonaldSole Yes, in the example sentences either will do because the things compared are of the same kind.  But can we broaden the question a little bit?  I agree with this answer, that I would never say “a bigger box than” something that is not a box. … On yet another hand, “I am a better writer than I am a dancer” is valid.

Comment: I think the explanation here was wrong.  First, there is nothing grammatically wrong with saying "a bigger box than (a car)", and the meaning is not different.  What I think you're getting at is that idiomatically, the "bigger x than y" construction is usually used only when "x" and "y" are in the same category.  This is really just an idiomatic convention, though (i.e. a "sounds wrong" sort of thing), and has nothing to do with different meanings or interpretations, except in some rare ambiguous cases.